# Why are Vector and HashTable widely believed to be due for deprecation?

Tags: java, vector, hashtable, deprecated

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Java Vector class is considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-java-vector-class-is-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

Also, is there an official word from Sun/Oracle on that?

Thanks.

EDIT:
I'm aware of the other topic, but it didn't mention whether there was an official word on this, which is why the topic is worded as "widely believed". Plus, that topic addresses only the Vector, not the Hashtable.

Comment: I'd really like to try and understand why this was "closed as exact duplicate" - I believe I've given fair reasons as to why it's not.

Answer (score 0):

`Vector` is synchronized; usually you don't need this as it incurs serious overhead.
`Hashtable` is also synchronized and can't reasonably store `null`s.

People use various Lists and `HashMap` instead.

Comment: Additionally, synchronizing on every single operation individually usually doesn't solve your concurrency problems anyway.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't the synchronizedList have the same limitation?